# Observable/Subscription ordering

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I don't have any code for this yet, I've just been doing a lot of reading and I have a question about what I want to implement.

I have three screens that push from one through to the other.

> Screen 1 --> Screen 2 --> Screen 3

I also have a provider that can make a `HTTP` call and keep the response in a variable that's an observable that I'll call `httpResponse$` for this example.

I want the `httpResponse$` to be used in Screen 3, but ideally, I'd like it to be populated before the user gets to Screen 3. So I make a call from Screen 1 to a function in the provider to get data and assign it to `httpResponse$`. Then in Screen 3, I want to subscribe to `httpResponse$`.

Now, it's my understanding that this won't work because when I make the call from Screen 1 to the provider, it will call a `.next` somewhere in the response, which will be undefined because it hasn't been subscribed to yet, because the user hasn't reached Screen 3.

Is this right? Is there a way of doing what I want to do here? That is populating data and then observing it for any changes later?

Comment: Look at ReplaySubject or BehaviorSubject

Comment: Thanks @Meir, a ReplaySubject is exactly what I'm looking for. You can chuck that in for an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rxjs` `ReplaySubject`. It emits the last (n) values for each new subscriber. BTW, make sure you do not terminate it by mistake, for example by using `take (1)` so that future subscribers can use it to